# How to detect mouse click on element inside WordPress Visual Editor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wp-editor

How to detect click on element inside WordPress Visual Editor using javascript?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution below :**

```js
jQuery(document).on('tinymce-editor-init', function(event, editor) {
  editor.on('click', function(e) {
    e = e.target;
    alert(e.nodeName);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="blue-button" onclick="myFunction()">Click</span>

<script>
function myFunction(){
 alert("Clicked")
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use `https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-and-footer-scripts/` this plugin for inject your custom js

Comment: I know how to enqueue script, I use wp_enqueue_script() function but that not afect elements inside the wp visual editor. To add custom TinyMCE editor stylesheets i use add_editor_style() but i don't know how to enqueue script for the TinyMCE editor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answer will help you, but for all click tracking on my website i use Google tag manager integrated with Google analytics. If you are open to considering this route i can link some videos that could help you

Comment: I don't want to Tracking clicks, i want to run some actions by clicking buttons inside the wp editor for Wordpress Plugin Development.